# Get rid of duplicate rows on conditions for a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with lots of duplicated rows on index, like this:

```
olddf = pd.DataFrame(index=['MJ','MJ','MJ','BJ','KJ','KJ'],data={'name':['masdjsdf','machael jordon','mskkkadke','boris johnson', 'kim jongun', 'kkasdfl'],'age':[23,40,31,35,25,30]})
```

I need to get rid of the duplicate index(rows) which also don't match the dictionary
`dic = {'MJ':'machael jordon', 'BJ':'boris johnson', 'KJ':'kim jongun'}.`
So after the operation, the dataframe should become

```
newdf = pd.DataFrame(index=['MJ','BJ','KJ'],data={'name':['machael jordon','boris johnson', 'kim jongun',],'age':[40,35,25]})
```

Thank you...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `map` to set the values from the dictionary keys, then `eq` to compare with the column's data. If equal this yields True, you can use the resulting Series of booleans as a mask to slice the original dataframe:

```
mask = olddf['name'].eq(olddf.index.map(dic))

newdf = olddf[mask]
```

Output:

```
              name  age
MJ  machael jordon   40
BJ   boris johnson   35
KJ      kim jongun   25
```

##### also keeping the non duplicated rows

Simple, add a second mask:

```
mask2 = ~olddf.index.duplicated(keep=False)

newdf = olddf[mask|mask2]
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for the solution! Works great to my question. I however find that I might need some change to my original problem.
Because I do not have all the index entry of olddf available in the dictionary. The dictionary is there only to help solve duplications. So if I use your method, I find that entries which don't exist in dictionary ( and don't have duplicates) were dropped. As an example, say if in my original problem, the dictionary doesn't have "BJ":"boris johnson" in it, I still need it to stay in the dataframe after the operation as it doesn't have a duplicate either.

Comment: @Alex see update ;)

Comment: How is the holiday going @mozway? :-) Map is cumbersome and can be quite slow. not handy in this situation I guess

Comment: @wwnde doing fine thanks ;) I wish you a happy new year. The issue with `isin` is that it will only check the values, ignoring the key (imagine a case where KJ would have a Boris Johnson value)

Comment: Thanks again. I can only say it works great at the moment as I have not used 'map' before. Time to digest the solution. Nice day!

Answer (score 0):

Take it easy, make it easy. Make the dic a pd.Series and check inclusion using .isin(). Code below

```
lst={'MJ':'machael jordon', 'BJ':'boris johnson', 'KJ':'kim jongun'}

olddf[olddf.isin(pd.Series(lst, name='name')).any(1)]
```

Alternatively create a dataframe dict. append the name column to index on both new and old df and then merge on index. left or inner merge would do. Code below

```
pd.DataFrame(pd.Series(lst, name='name')).set_index('name', append=True).merge(olddf.set_index('name', append=True), how='left',left_index=True, right_index=True )
```

Outcome

```
            name  age
MJ  machael jordon   40
BJ   boris johnson   35
KJ      kim jongun   25
```

Comment: I think you meant `olddf['name'].isin(pd.Series(dic, name='name'))` not `any` that would use the age column ;)

Comment: Yes, but we are associating by index and name to filter. Moreless an inner merge on index and name as  I see it @mozway

Comment: I see, then use `olddf[['name']].isin(pd.Series(dic, name='name'))['name']` this prevents uselessly (and perhaps wrongly, in case there is a collision) checking the other columns

Comment: Okay, we can then try `pd.DataFrame(pd.Series(lst, name='name')).set_index('name', append=True).merge(olddf.set_index('name', append=True), how='left',left_index=True, right_index=True )` I would prefer this to map.

Comment: No sure why we got DV, but this made me realize I forgot to UV your answer ;)

Comment: Not sure too gave you my +1

Comment: Hey just wanna say thank you for the answer. I tried your first solution but it could not keep the index entry that's not in the dictionary. The second solution did not work in my working problem. I'll go with mozway's solution. :)

Comment: I do not see why it should not work. There is no technical explanation as to why. Anyway you seem to have go a solution. Happy coding. Keep coding

Answer (score 0):

```
dic = {'MJ':'machael jordon', 'BJ':'boris johnson', 'KJ':'kim jongun'}
olddf.join(pd.Series(dic).to_frame('name'),rsuffix='_2').query("name==name_2")

         name  age          name_2
BJ   boris johnson   35   boris johnson
KJ      kim jongun   25      kim jongun
MJ  machael jordon   40  machael jordon
```